# how to make function in PHP with repeatedly querying a database

Tags: php, mysql, function

My Code is working but i'm not satisfied with this, it looks very dirty.
My Problem is, How can I make a function for my code to be not repeating.
Here's my code,

```
    <?php
// PARENT MENU
$q2 = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = (SELECT MIN(parent) from userpage) ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
$r2 = $db->query($q2);
$a2 = $db->fetch_all_array($q2);
foreach($a2 as $k => $v)
  {
    $indent = "&#10149;";
    $tab = "&emsp;";
    $menu_id = $v['m_id'];
    echo $v['pagename'] . "(" . $v['page'] . ")";
    // 1ST SUB MENU
    if ($menu_id != '')
      {
        $q3 = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = " . $menu_id . " ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
        $r3 = $db->query($q3);
        $a3 = $db->fetch_all_array($q3);
        foreach($a3 as $k3 => $v3)
          {
            $menu_id2 = $v3['m_id'];
            echo $v3['pagename'] . "(" . $v3['page'] . ")";
            // 2ND SUB MENU
            if ($menu_id2 != '')
              {
                $q4 = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = " . $menu_id2 . " ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
                $r4 = $db->query($q4);
                $a4 = $db->fetch_all_array($q4);
                foreach($a4 as $k4 => $v4)
                  {
                    $menu_id3 = $v4['m_id'];
                    echo $v4['pagename'] . "(" . $v4['page'] . ")";
                    // 3RD SUB MENU
                    if ($menu_id3 != '')
                      {
                        $q5 = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = " . $menu_id3 . " ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
                        $r5 = $db->query($q5);
                        $a5 = $db->fetch_all_array($q5);
                        foreach($a5 as $k5 => $v5)
                          {
                            $menu_id4 = $v5['m_id'];
                            echo $v5['pagename'] . "(" . $v5['page'] . ")";
                            // 4TH SUB MENU
                            if ($menu_id4 != '')
                              {
                                $q6 = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = " . $menu_id4 . " ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
                                $r6 = $db->query($q6);
                                $a6 = $db->fetch_all_array($q6);
                                foreach($a6 as $k6 => $v6)
                                  {
                                    $menu_id5 = $v6['m_id'];
                                    echo $v6['pagename'] . "(" . $v6['page'] . ")";
                                    // 5TH SUB MENU
                                    if ($menu_id5 != '')
                                      {
                                        $q7 = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = " . $menu_id5 . " ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
                                        $r7 = $db->query($q7);
                                        $a7 = $db->fetch_all_array($q7);
                                        foreach($a7 as $k7 => $v7)
                                          {
                                            $menu_id6 = $v7['m_id'];
                                            echo $v['pagename'] . "(" . $v['page'] . ")";
                                          } //5th submenu
                                      } //closing if for 5th submenu
                                  } //4th submenu
                              } //closing if for 4th submenu
                          } //3rd submenu
                      } //closing if for 3rd submenu
                  } //2nd submenu
              } //closing if for 2nd submenu
          } //1st submenu
      } //closing if for 1st submenu
  } //parent menu
?>
```

Thank You.
Any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a good task for `recursion`. Google it :)

Comment: It may help if you can explain to us what your code is meant to be doing. Commenting your code is a universal win for programming. Try and do it.

Comment: Thank you for answering, you guys are right. 
My program is to display all the pages as menu format.

Comment: If you know how to make functions, all you have to do is recognize patterns and create a function that can do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code to use recursion.  The simplest way to do this will still call the database multiple times but you won't need them all in code.

Calling the function below will write out the submenu and all its children / grandchildren etc...

It works using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) which in this context means the function calls itself to complete its task.

```
function subMenu($menu_id) {
    $q = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = " . $menu_id . " ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
    $r = $db->query($q);
    $a = $db->fetch_all_array($q);
    foreach($a2 as $k => $v)
    {
        $menu_id2 = $v['m_id'];
        echo $v['pagename'] . "(" . $v['page'] . ")";
        if ($menu_id2 != '') {
            // write out the submenu of this submenu
            subMenu($menu_id2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

With an indent counter.  Pass in `0` to `indent_count`

```
function subMenu($menu_id, $indent_count) {
    $q = "SELECT t.*, t2.id as m_id FROM userpage t left join menu t2 on (t2.parent=t.parent and t2.sort=t.sort) WHERE t.parent = " . $menu_id . " ORDER BY t.sort ASC";
    $r = $db->query($q);
    $a = $db->fetch_all_array($q);
    foreach($a2 as $k => $v)
    {
        $menu_id2 = $v['m_id'];
        // You need to add in an indent based on $indent_count
        echo $v['pagename'] . "(" . $v['page'] . ")";
        if ($menu_id2 != '') {
            // write out the submenu of this submenu
            subMenu($menu_id2, $indent_count + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is what i'm looking for.
But my problem now is- I need to display it with indention.

Comment: Not a problem.  I've given an alternative that shows how to keep track of how deep the code has recursed.

Comment: Nice ! You're such a genius! Now I know. Thank you! You solved my problem.